# Check if there's images on a folder

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using an slideshow and I would like check if there any image on a specific folder since I'll make it all dynamically.
I saw some questions here about this but can't get it work.

```
<div class="foo">
    <img src="images/[dynamic_folder_name]/1.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="images/[dynamic_folder_name]/2.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

There'll be allot of folders and maybe some could be empty so I wanna check with jquery if there's any images with those names and if not set a default image.

If you have any other ideas for doing this instead of using jquery, you're more than welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user , how are you generating images , on the server side or client side , i mean where are u determining the dynamic folder name

Comment: @user ideally as best practices you should do the processing work in the back , which is server side.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript runs within the clients browser which has no knowledge of your servers folder structure. You'll need to create a server script which supplies the required information to the scripts running in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use script like this.

```
function testImage(src,callback) {
var testimg = new Image();
testimg.onerror(function(){    
    callback(false);    
});
testimg.onload(function(){    
    callback(true);    
});
testimg.load(src);
}
```

Then call the function to check if image exeist.